# Getting a Runtime error when passing an Integer into a Solidity function that take uint256 as parameter

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethers.js

My Solidity smart contract has this function:

```
function getPlayerAddress(uint256 index) public view returns(address) {
        return s_players[index];
    }
```

And I am trying to pass an Integer as parameter via my frontend React application.

This is what the State looks like:

```
const [playerIndex, setPlayerIndex] = useState(0)
```

This is the function where I am trying to pass the value:

```
const updatePlayer = async () => {
        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
        const contract = new ethers.Contract(stallionRunAddress, abi, provider)
        **const newPlayer = await contract.getPlayerAddress(playerIndex)**
        const newPlayerLevelBI = await contract.ownedHorseLevel(newPlayer)
        const newPlayerLevel = parseInt(newPlayerLevelBI)
        const newPlayerHorseArr = await contract.ownedHorseName(newPlayer)
        const newPlayerHorse = newPlayerHorseArr[0].toString()
        setPlayers(...players, {address: newPlayer, level: newPlayerLevel, horse: newPlayerHorse})
    }
```

I get this error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error

Error: call revert exception; VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with panic code 50 [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="getPlayerAddress(uint256)", data="0x4e487b710000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000032", errorArgs=[{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x32"}], errorName="Panic", errorSignature="Panic(uint256)", reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.7.0)
```

I have tried passing it as a value with 18 decimals (wei format):

```
playerIndex * 1e18
```

But it still doesn't fix the error. How do i fix this?

Comment: Try to pass integer as string

Comment: But the solidity function accepts a uint256. How will that work?

Comment: Everything is always converted to byte calldata so no problem just pass as string or bignumber on javascript sidr

Answer (score 0):

Solidity uint256 integers can be passed by web3js should be BigNumber instead of js integers. Also you can use string as well.